# Does javax.crypto.KeyGenerator uses /random or /urandom to generate keys?

Tags: java, random, cryptography, virtual-machine, entropy

Consider the following snippet where I use AES-256 to generate keys to encrypt - the thread which runs the following snippet gets blocked. I'm suspecting whether this could be due to the problem that sufficient entropy is not reached. So, that the thread could suspend (or) looks hanging till sufficient entropy is gathered by the system.

I run this on a virtual machine and not on a physical one and I'm using Java8.

**SNIPPET A**

```
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(256);
SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();
```

The following [article](https://tersesystems.com/blog/2015/12/17/the-right-way-to-use-securerandom/) infers that `SecureRandom` instance when obtained as

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
```

The `NativePRNG` algorithm which is used by default to generate entropy is referred as `SHA1PRNG` which uses `/dev/urandom` by default and hence no thread blocking could occur.

I'll come to the point why I'm speaking about these stuffs. The line

```
keyGen.init(256);
```

in the above snippet does the following action internally.

```
 public final void init(int paramInt) {
     init(paramInt, JceSecurity.RANDOM);
 }
```

and what this `JceSecurity.RANDOM` has is this

```
static final SecureRandom RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
```

Means it should have used [`/dev/urandom`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) and this shouldn't have blocked (or) hanged when the entropy is not gathered.

I'm sharing my [java.security](https://docs.zoho.com/download/4xwcw8f2b548be30641ccbe38c0a36cf18cbc) file here.

Can someone shed some insight on why the above thread which runs the `SNIPPET A` blocks?

Comment: First question is: can you provide MCVE which reproduces this issue with blocking?

Comment: Not trying to be silly.. Are you asking about a complete snippet from where I could reproduce the issue @Andremoniy

Comment: I am asking about MCVE, might be shared somewhere on GitHub if it is quite big, or just complete class with main method and all needed logic. Because it sounds like a JVM bug, or it can be just kind of non-reproducible misconfiguration or misusage inside your code (for instance, if you use keyGenerator in shared memory between multiple threads).

Comment: @Andremoniy : Here is the complete class file https://docs.zoho.com/file/4xwcwd7e074921bb14c829d6d41dc58515106

Comment: This is definitely not an MCVE.

Comment: I could reproduce the bug with this snippet @Andremoniy that's why I'm sharing you this one..

Comment: You should remove from this snipper everything unrelated to the problem: e.g. ZooKeeper and so on. Leave only minimal code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Yeah sure @Andremoniy. Here is the edited link https://docs.zoho.com/file/4xwcwd7e074921bb14c829d6d41dc58515106

Comment: I've tried this code and it works fine without any blocking. Do you want to say that this particular code being run in your environment gets blocked?

Comment: Yeah exactly!! @Andremoniy And one more thing does this ‘KeyGenerator’ uses urandom internally? Want to be clear on how KeyGenerator generates random bytes too..

Comment: What JDK version do you use to compile the code, and which JRE do you use to run the code?

Comment: Open jdk version 1.8.0_131 and JRE is (Zulu 8.21.0.1-linux64) 64-bit server VM

Comment: Why do you believe the thread is blocking at `keyGen.Init()`?

Comment: I'm just doubting it ;-) because it uses `SecureRandom` internally :-)

Comment: Perhaps [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr016.html) or related may be better at diagnosing the problem than making educated guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end a random number generator will always depend on the entropy sources of the operating system, if just for seeding; it is impossible to generate random numbers from non-random environment after all.

I can imagine that a VM with limited amount of entropy sources has trouble filling up the entry pool, if just once. The best way to resolve this issue is to make sure that your VM has the latest client additions installed. Those could / should make the hosts RNG available to the client machine.

It is possible to once create a `SecureRandom` instance and pass it as parameter to the various `init()` methods. However, that would not solve blocking it right at the start, and it unnecessarily complicates code.  Finally, you'll never know which library or module still instantiates another `SecureRandom` instance.

So I'd focus on fixing the RNG of the client VM rather than the Java code.

---

Note that `NativePRNG` uses the OS RNG directly; it does not use `"SHA1PRNG"`. The `SecureRandom()` uses the first provider that contains an implementation of the class; make sure you haven't included a provider with a slow PRNG if the default PRNG is used.

Comment: "make sure you haven't included a provider with a slow PRNG if the default PRNG is used" - I'm not clear with this.

I have the following configuration in my security file, **securerandom.source=file:/dev/random** So, "NativePRNG" implementation would be preferred - so, it uses /dev/random and **not /dev/urandom** right?

Comment: Yeah, and that would be blocking if not enough entropy is gathered. In general the use of `/dev/random` doesn't have many (if *any*) advantages over `/dev/urandom`. Only use it if you're generating long term (asymmetric) keys - and even then I would use it with extreme caution or go for the more reliable `/dev/urandom`. It seems that somebody was a little too security conscious over there :)

Comment: What are client additions?

Comment: Depending on the VM solution used VM client extensions allow such things as clipboard copy and paste, but also e.g. graphics acceleration. They need to be installed after the client OS is installed. They may install specific drivers, sometimes including a driver to connect to the secure RNG of the host OS. I've used a generic term, as the name depends on the VM application used.